# Laravel Relationships: Users - Morph Many Through?

Tags: laravel, relationship

I am trying to get all users that belong to two models.

I have ***Bursary Administrators*** who can have many ***Students*** and then ***Users*** who are normal Bursary Administrator users or Student users.

I am trying to fetch all users that belong to students that belong to a bursary administrator.

**Bursary Administrator Model**

```
public function students () {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class)->withPivot('bursary_administrator_reference')->withTimestamps();
}
public function users() {
    return $this->morphMany(User::class, 'userable');
}
```

**Student Model**

```
public function bursary_administrators():BelongsToMany {
    return $this->belongsToMany(BursaryAdministrator::class)->withPivot('bursary_administrator_reference')->withTimestamps();
}
```

And I need to add something to the Bursary Administrator Model like...

```
public function student_users () {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class)->using(User::class)->where('users.userable_type','App\Models\Student');
}
```

So at the end of the day, I am looking to do something like:

```
$ba = BursaryAdministrator::find(1);
$ba->student_users()->get();
```

The SQL for this is easy, Im just struggling with translating this to Laravel Relationships:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN bursary_administrator_student ON 
users.`userable_id`=bursary_administrator_student.student_id
INNER JOIN students ON bursary_administrator_student.student_id=students.id
WHERE userable_type="App\\Models\\Student"
```